# react-native navigation menu bottom docked navigation menu

Tags: react-native

Am learning `react-native`, trying to create a menu docked at the bottom of a screen. Is there a way i can display the screen content in the ScrollView docked at the top of navigation menu [like this messenger menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt011.jpg) ? When messages image is tapped, display messages screen content in the same page.

```
         return (<View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView>
            <Text style={styles.content}>
              {this.state.content}</Text>
          </ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.footer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateMessage}>
              <Image source={require('../img/messages.png')} style={[
                  styles.tabIcon, {
                    tintColor: this.state.messagesTint
                  }
                ]}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateContacts}>
              <Image source={require('../img/contacts.png')} style={[
                  styles.tabIcon, {
                    tintColor: this.state.contactsTint
                  }
                ]}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native re-renders the content when the state changes/you call setState().

You can follow this.

```
state = {
    selectedTab: 'msg'
}
renderMessages(){
    return <YourMessageView />
}
render(){
    switch(this.state.selectedTab){
        case 'msg':
            this.renderMessages();
            break;
        case 'contact':
            this.renderContact();
            break;
        default:
            this.renderDefault();

    } 
    return(
      <YourFooter />
    );


}
```

and on your TouchableOpacity onPress:

```
onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'msg'})}
```